# Increment variable number and assign new value

Tags: linux, shell, variables

I'm trying to assign values from a list to a set of variables. The variable number start from 1 and keeps increasing according to the number of values in the list.
I did a quick `for` loop, but I get errors.

```
list="010 110 004"
num=0
for node in `echo $list`
do
    ((num+=1))
    node_$num="my_host-$node.test.edu.com"
    echo $node_$num
done
```

But I get errors like this:

```
bash: node_1=my_host-010.test.edu.com: command not found
1
bash: node_2=my_host-110.test.edu.com: command not found
2
bash: node_3=my_host-004.test.edu.com: command not found
3
```

How can I assign values from the list to an increasing set of variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should have it in `bash`:

```
list=(010 110 004)
num=0

for node in "${list[@]}"; do
    ((num+=1))
    var="node_$num"

    # use declare to create and instanitate var=value
    declare "$var"="my_host-$node.test.edu.com"

    # examine value o f$var
    declare -p "$var"
    # or use this echo to print just value
    # echo "${!var}"
done
```

```
declare -- node_1="my_host-010.test.edu.com"
declare -- node_2="my_host-110.test.edu.com"
declare -- node_3="my_host-004.test.edu.com"
```

Also note use of shell arrays for safe iteration of a finite list of items.

Comment: Thanks for this. But now I've another query.... the $var is getting replaced in each iteration.. I don't want that, as I plan to use the variables $node_$num in remaining part of my script.

Comment: No, ignore temp $var. Your actual variables node_1, node_2 etc will be available for other part of script.

Comment: I'm still confused how to use "$var" in my script. For e.g. if I want to put the variable in a file with other normal variables, how should I do it? 

Will this work echo "$var, $my_other_var1, $my_other_var2" >> /tmp/some_file.out

Comment: No need to use $var any where else. You need to use $node_1, $node_2 etc in your script.

Comment: Also I wonder what is `$my_other_var1`, `$my_other_var2` etc since there is no reference of these variables in question.